# Modules 'base' and 'player' contain entry 'res/layout/exo_playback_control_view.xml' with different content

Tags: android, exoplayer, dynamic-feature, dynamic-feature-module

I work on an app with multiple Dynamic Modules.

In order to add the video download's feature to my app, I need to add the ExoPlayer UI dependency (`com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.11.1`) to my *base* module.
Since I already have this dependency in my *player* module, I have this compilation error message :

> **Modules 'base' and 'player' contain entry 'res/layout/exo_playback_control_view.xml' with different content.**

Since I can't rename the ExoPlayer generated layout file, I've tried to get ride of this file from my *base* module since I only need it into my *player* module.

So far I've tried :

```
sourceSets {
        main.res.srcDirs += 'src/main/res'

        main {
            res {
                exclude 'res/layout/exo_playback_control_view.xml'
                exclude 'layout/exo_playback_control_view.xml'
                exclude 'exo_playback_control_view.xml'
                exclude 'library/ui/src/main/res/layout/exo_playback_control_view.xml'
            }
        }
    }
```

And

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude 'res/layout/exo_playback_control_view.xml'
        exclude 'layout/exo_playback_control_view.xml'
        exclude 'exo_playback_control_view.xml'
        exclude 'library/ui/src/main/res/layout/exo_playback_control_view.xml'
    }
```

Any of these works. 
I am not comfortable with Gradle as you probably can see.

I've also opened an [issue](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/7102) on the ExoPlayer Github repository.

Does anyone have another idea to avoid this compilation error?

Comment: What was the issue ?

Comment: @JhamanDas If you mean the ExoPlayer issue, here it is : https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/7102